# Is there any point where RTMFP's overall 128-bit encryption for stream turns into 256-bit encryption?

Tags: security, encryption, network-protocols, rtmfp

This is very similar to another question I'm asking, but still a little different.  Both questions are attacking the same problem, and I really just need one or the other answered:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443236/how-can-you-make-rtmfp-encrypt-streams-using-256-bits-not-128

Basically I know that RTMFP, for the most part, uses 128-bit encryption for streaming.  But is this statement just an over-generalization to some extent?  Is there some particular part of the process, while streaming audio and video, specifically on which it uses 256-bit encryption?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason it needs to be 256-bit? AES-256 is slower than AES-128, and so I'd imagine for streaming video protocols, depending on the threat model, it's a bit overkill.

Comment: It's something that one of our customers is asking for.

Comment: @Panzercrisis ask the customer to count the number of digits in 2^126

Comment: @Rajesh you mean 1^128, and because `ln 2 / ln 10 = 0.3` I would expect the number of digits should be about 37.

Comment: @owlstead not a mistake there, the best known attack on full AES is only better than a brute force by a factor of 4. [Biclique cryptanalysis of the full AES](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/cryptanalysis/aes.aspx)

Comment: hashes?  hash --> send --> rtmfp encryption happens here --> unhash --> read  does this not add that layer?

Comment: Can you do that in AS3 while streaming live video and audio?